# What's the most efficient way to filter on categorie with jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, json

I'm pretty new to programming and right now I have a website that shows different fireworks from my json file in the frontend. I have made a categories menu, that I would like to actually work. I wondered what would be the most efficient way to make this menu work. I have made a function that returns all existing json objects from my json file, and wondered if it would be possible to use this existing function to filter on the different categories, and only show the items with the designated categorie. The script I'm using to loop through all de json object is:

```
$(function(){
$.getJSON("assets/products/sample_products.json", function(response) {
    $.each(response.data, function (i, el) {
        let card = $($('#productCard-template').html());
        card.find('.container > p').html( el.name + '<br> &euro;' +  el.price );
        card.find('.productItem').attr('data-price', el.price)
            .attr('data-article-number', el.article_number)
            .attr('data-id', el.id)
            .attr('data-name', el.name)
            .attr('data-slug', el.slug);
        $('#touchViewProducts').append(card);
    });
});
```

});

The filter function:

```
//filter function
$(".nav-link").click(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('id');
    if (category != "all") {
        $(".productCard").hide();
        $(".productCard").each(function() {
            if ($(this).find(".productItem").attr('data-slug') == category) {
                $(this).show() //show that div
            }
        })
    } else {
        $(".productCard").show();
    }
})
```

This is the template the data gets shown in on the frontend:

```
 <script type="text/template" id="productCard-template">
        <div class="col-3 productCard">
            <a href="#" class="productItem">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="assets/images/Firecracker.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width: 100%; height: 8vh;">
                    <div class="container">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </script>
```

This is an example of the code in my json file, I would like to filter on 'slug' : {

```
"data":[
    {
      "id":"1333",
      "article_number":"4016",
      "barcode":"heeftgeenbarcode4",
      "name":"White Albino",
      "stock":null,
      "to_sell":null,
      "price":"50",
      "brand":{
        "id":"26",
        "name":"Fireworks Festival",
        "slug":"grond-en-siervuurwerk",
        "logo_path":"\/uploads\/product-brands\/26\/5d8e3cd1a865f.png"
      },
```

Menu html:

```
  <div class="col-3 categoriesSection">
                    <div class="categories">
                        <p style="background-color: white; margin-bottom: 0px" > Categories </p>
                        <a class="nav-link" id="all" href="#">All</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" id="black-thunder" href="#">Black-thunder</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" id="blue-eagle-fireworks" href="#">Blue-eagle-fireworks</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" id="crystal-exclusive" href="#">Crystal-exclusive</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" id="empire-fireworks" href="#">Empire-fireworks</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" id="grondbloemen" href="#">Grondbloemen</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I hope everything is clear, thank you!

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Andreas as stated, I'm pretty new to this stuff. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi , how do you need to filter ? on click of button ? how do you know which `slug` to filter ? Please elaborate more ..

Comment: @Swati   hanks for the reply, I've made a menu with different 'slugs' that can be found in the json file. I would like the page to be filled with products with the selected slug. I will add the html of the menu to the edit!

Comment: You need to filter onclick of `a` tag ? Also here `.attr('data-slug', el.slug);` you are storing value of slug in `a` tag of products? and here `grond-en-siervuurwerk` where is this in your menu ?

Comment: @Swati I forgot that slug in the menu indeed, thanks for noticing. I'm retrieving different data of the products and storing them in de a tag of products indeed. That way I can later use this data to add different products to the shopping cart and later to the database when they get sold. So the onclick function woul apply to the a tags on the nav links, and clicking one of the nav links would have to make every item without the slug selected disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `click` event here when user click on `a` tag get the `id` which has different category then loop through all `productCard` divs and check if the *a* tag inside it has `data-slug` equal to the category which user has selected depending on this show that div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".nav-link").click(function() {
  //get id of the a tag
  var category = $(this).attr('id');
  //check is not "all"
  if (category != "all") {
    //hide product div
    $(".productCard").hide();
    //loop through product div
    $(".productCard").each(function() {
      //check data-slug == category which user has clicked
      if ($(this).find(".productItem").attr('data-slug') == category) {
        $(this).show() //show that div
      }
    })
  } else {

    $(".productCard").show();
  }

})
```

```css
.productCard {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-3 categoriesSection">
  <div class="categories">
    <p style="background-color: white; margin-bottom: 0px"> Categories </p>
    <a class="nav-link" id="all" href="#">All</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="black-thunder" href="#">Black-thunder</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="blue-eagle-fireworks" href="#">Blue-eagle-fireworks</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="crystal-exclusive" href="#">Crystal-exclusive</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="empire-fireworks" href="#">Empire-fireworks</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="grondbloemen" href="#">Grondbloemen</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-3 productCard">
  <a href="#" class="productItem" data-slug="crystal-exclusive">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/images/Firecracker.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width: 100%; height: 8vh;">
      <div class="container">
        <p>test wwrbrb crystal-exclusive</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-3 productCard">
  <a href="#" class="productItem" data-slug="black-thunder">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/images/Firecracker.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="">
      <div class="container">
        <p>testbrbr black-thunder</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-3 productCard">
  <a href="#" class="productItem" data-slug="grondbloemen">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/images/Firecracker.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Soemthing 3 grondbloemen</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-3 productCard">
  <a href="#" class="productItem" data-slug="grondbloemen">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/images/Firecracker.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Soemthing 2 grondbloemen</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-3 productCard">
  <a href="#" class="productItem" data-slug="empire-fireworks">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/images/Firecracker.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Soemthing 2 empire-fireworks</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-3 productCard">
  <a href="#" class="productItem" data-slug="blue-eagle-fireworks">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="assets/images/Firecracker.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Soemthing 2 blue-eagle-fireworks</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the good solution, it's very clear to me now. The 'all' does work, but for some reason, filter on id doesn't work for me, everything is hidden when I press one of the categories other than 'all'.

Comment: Make sure `id` and `data-slug` should have same value .. also in your code provided you have `attr('data-name', el.slug);` that should be `attr('data-slug', el.slug);` change that and see

Comment: I did that, I updated the code in the question to my most recent code now so you should be able to see it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it didn't, sadly.

Comment: Did you check if the values are same ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221940/discussion-between-swati-and-yoverflow).